# dependency, sudo, and apt-get errors in Kubuntu

Tags: apt, sudo, dependencies

It's been awhile since I've used my Kubuntu system. I'm trying to upgrade to version 16.04 - and running into a series of problems:

1. When attempting to upgrade Kubuntu to version 16.04, I get the error message:

   ```
   Required depends is not installed
   The required dependency 'apt (>= 1.0.1ubuntu2.13)' is not installed.
   ```
2. So, when I attempt to fix that in the (Konsole) Terminal, I enter:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade apt
   ```

   The response that I get is:

   ```
   Command 'sudo' is available in '/usr/bin/sudo'
   The command could not be located because '/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
   sudo: command not found
   ```
3. I then try to fix that by entering:

   ```
   apt-get install sudo
   ```

   The response that I get to this is:

   ```
   Command 'apt-get' is available in '/usr/bin/apt-get'
   The command could not be located because '/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
   apt-get: command not found
   ```
4. I tried to address that by entering:

   ```
   export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin
   sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade apt
   ```

   In response, I get:

   ```
   E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
   E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
   ```
5. In order to identify what might be causing the problem, I ran:

   ```
   ps aux | grep apt
   ```

   The only thing that comes up that looks like it *might* be a possibility is this:

   ```
   4381  0.0  0.0  11740   936 pts/2    S+   23:50   0:00 grep --color=auto apt
   ```

(All the other "apt"s it finds are part of "caption"...)

At this point, where should I go? What should I try?

Comment: I suggest you back up your personal data and do a clean install of Kubuntu 1**8**.04.1 unless you have very specific reasons for moving to 16.04.

Comment: If you are trying to upgrade to Kubuntu 16.04, what are you running now?    Standard LTS upgrades only go to the next LTS, so you'd have to be on 14.04 LTS to `do-release-upgrade` to 16.04 LTS, but your `apt` appears much older than 14.04.5 (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=apt) or your system wasn't upgraded to latest before `do-release-upgrade`